# Wacom Bamboo PAD stylus gets 'stuck' on clicking/dragging

Tags: drivers, touchpad, tablet, wacom

Since I've switched to Ubuntu, my Wacom tablet stylus has stopped clicking and drawing. When I press it, it does not click, and when I drag it, it does not move. When I release it it would change its position in an instant to where it is now. My finger works fine on it, only the stylus is the problem.

Solutions I've tried:

1. Installing input-wacom from Linux Wacom using apt-get
2. Installing the x-driver from Linux Wacom using apt-get
3. Installing the above drivers from download and source
4. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1515562

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

it's such an old post. I'm also having the same problem with **Wacom Bamboo CTH-301** on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Has anybody found the solution?

I've tried reading all the parameters to try to wonder if it's a miss-configuration ( ***xsetwacom --list devices ; xsetwacom --get 'Wacom USB Bamboo PAD Pen stylus' all*** ) but I can't find it.

Any idea?
Thanks and best regards,